# Safely wiring two strands of halloween LED string lights in series?

Tags: batteries, ac, dc, lighting, string

I have ~20 ft of perimeter to cover and it seems everything sold online is sold by ~10 ft lengths.

I've decided I want to buy two strands of [these lights](https://www.amazon.ca/Quntis-Halloween-Decoration-Waterproof-Multicolor/dp/B08DNVR5F2/ref=sr_1_8?dchild=1&keywords=Halloween%20lights&qid=1602966165&sr=8-8) and connect them start to end.

What considerations do I need to take in to account here? I plan on powering both from mains using something to convert the power from mains down to the ~5V (actually 4.5) we could expect from three AA batteries in series, [this is what I've chosen for now.](https://www.amazon.ca/BOLWEO-Universal-Connector-Household-Electronic/dp/B07QNTF9G8/ref=sr_1_10?dchild=1&keywords=5v%20power%20supply&qid=1602965797&sr=8-10)

Now because these are all in series, I'll require a higher voltage right? Double the length so double the voltage, (4.5 * 2 = 9) right? Anyone ever done something like this that can provide some help, thanks!

Comment: 4.5V is too low to put so many LED's in series. My guess is these are all in parallel. In which case you can just connect the second string in parallel with the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Put both battery boxes in the middle and supply 5V from a phone charger.

Comment: I'd rather not supply power to the centre of the combined 20-ft strand. Wouldn't be useful unless I could power it from one end.

Comment: you'll probably have to add a 10 foot cable from one end to the middle, I can't see a simple solution that doesn't involve that.

Answer (score 1):

It rather depends what you mean by "connect them in series".

A string of multiple LEDs designed to run on 4.5 to 5V will have all the LEDs in parallel, with current limiting resistors as required.  That resistance may well be in the control box - white LEDs are intended to run on about 3V.  If you connect two LED strings end-to-end, then you will be adding more LEDs in parallel with each other.  You will need the same voltage, but a power supply that can deliver double the current.

But if you actually do intend to run the two strings in series - the negative line of one connected to the positive of the next, then you will need double the voltage.

Comment: by in series I mean to connect them start to end. Not literally wired as series but I just want a 20 ft rope, not a 10 ft rope if that makes sense